# uwp async method skipping code lines

Tags: c#, asynchronous, methods, async-await, win-universal-app

I have an async method with void return type. Here it is

```
public static async void LoadPlaylists()
{
    if(playlistitems.Count==0)
    {
        var playlists = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFilesAsync();
        var c = playlists.Count;
        foreach (var playlist in playlists)
        {
            var p = await Playlist.LoadAsync(playlist);
            var image = new BitmapImage();
            if (p.Files.Count == 0)
            {
                image.UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Wide310x150Logo.scale-200.png");
            }
            else
            {
                image = await Thumbnail(p.Files[0]);
            }
            playlistitems.Add
            (
                new PlaylistItem
                {
                    playlist = p,
                    PlaylistName = playlist.DisplayName,
                    NumOfVid = p.Files.Count.ToString(),
                    Thumbnail = image
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

It is a public static method so I can use it anywhere, I use it on one page to load some data and it works fine,and it completes this method and then move forward on next code line. as shown below

```
private void l1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //some more code
    LoadPlaylists();
    //some more code
}
```

But when I use it on another page in another event handler, which is not async method, it just runs the first line, and then it skips whole method and moves forward. I know for sure that it is skipping those lines, bcz i checked with break point, I know it is skipping because it is async but I dnt want that, I just want it to complete the whole method and then move forward. S o that I dont get any problem on next code lines. I am pasting the code below again, to show you with comments what it skipps.

```
public static async void LoadPlaylists()
{
    if(playlistitems.Count==0)
    {
        //it runs till here, when compiler goes to line below
        //it skips whole methods and exits it.
        var playlists = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFilesAsync();
        var c = playlists.Count;
        foreach (var playlist in playlists)
        {
            var p = await Playlist.LoadAsync(playlist);
            var image = new BitmapImage();
            if (p.Files.Count == 0)
            {
                image.UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Wide310x150Logo.scale-200.png");
            }
            else
            {
                image = await Thumbnail(p.Files[0]);
            }

            playlistitems.Add
            (
                new PlaylistItem
                {
                    playlist = p,
                    PlaylistName = playlist.DisplayName,
                    NumOfVid = p.Files.Count.ToString(),
                    Thumbnail = image
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Now below is the code where I am using it in an async event handler, and whre it is causing me problem.

```
    private async void ME_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        //When used here, it just skippes everything in the method
        //as i described on the comments in code above.

        LoadPlaylists();

        //after skipping the compiler comes here and tries to execute
        //the lines below, which obviously causes exceptions because
        above method was never completed to begin with.

        var sd = playlistitems.Count;
        //some more code
    }
```

Comment: Return the Task instead of void so that you can await for the method to complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should return the Task instead of void so that you can await for the method to complete.

Comment: async programming is always confusing me thanks a lot :)